# store json.stringify() data in java object returned by ajax call from js

Tags: json, stringify

In JSP, I entered 10 persons details like first name, last name, age and contact and AJAX call returned this 10 persons data using `json.stringify(formdata)` method...

i want to store these 10 persons data in List, in java please suggest the best way

I have tried to retrieve using `context().getRequest.getparametersnames()`
and iterated one by one and read the first name, last name and remaining values like this, stored in person object and added finally to List/

In this case the order is changing some times. If possible in simple steps suggest me the optimal way..

Answer (score 0):

You can try json.parse() to parse something which is received from json.stringify()

Good luck!

Comment: if i am able to store it then i can use this json.parse() method but that is what i can't do, thanks for the interest.